# Laravel 3: Extending a controller from a bundle

Tags: php, laravel, bundle, laravel-3

Is it possible to extend a controller from a bundle starting from your application controller by namespaces? I have tried a lot of different approaches, but none of theme worked.

This is what I'm trying to get working:

:: application - controller:

```
News_Controller extends Bundle_News_Controller
```

:: bundle controller

```
Bundle_News_Controller extends Bundle_Base_Controller
```

Comment: If you have the bundle started I'd say it should work. Do you get errors? Why don't they work?

Comment: That it can't find the controller (in the bundle). But I also asked the question on the Laravel forum, here I got this answer from Phill Sparks: http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=8272. 

At the moment, I use the mapping from bundles.